# How to fix Camera View

Tags: camera

Edited: The problem solved, by user [vklidu](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/2214/vklidu).

---

I use Blender 3.4.1

I press Numpad 0, my Camera View is distortion badly.
I press F12 to Render, the result is normal.

I don't know what i did that made this happen.
Anyone can help me how to fix this? So i can fix if it happen again in future.

[image: SS 1 of 5 : Layout workspace : Camera Settings is default]

[image: SS 2 of 5 : Layout workspace : i press Numpad 0 : Camera View is broken]

[image: SS 3 of 5 : Layout workspace : i press F12 : The Rendered result is normal, based on Camera View]

[image: SS 4 of 5 : Shading workspace : i press Numpad 0 : Camera View is normal]

[image: SS 5 of 5 : Shading workspace : i press F12 : The Rendered result is normal, based on Camera View]

I'm new in Blender.
I'm still an early learning.

Regards,
Geo

Comment: Just zoom your view. You can still zoom and pan around while looking through your camera. But if you rotate your view it will snap out of camera view

Comment: to add to Vklidu's answer, the distortion comes from the camera focal lens, you can change it but it will also change the image perspective

Comment: You don't need to edit in "Problem solved" and give the name of the user who solved it. That's what we have an answers section here for and why it is welcome to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable **Camera to View** in 3DViewport seen in your screen in properties (N) panel on the right side and Shift+Alt move view to centre. Than enable "Camera to View" back to navigate through your camera again ... or go to header View > Camera > **Frame Camera Bounds**.

Comment: Thank you vklidu , for the step by step help.
I uncheck the Camera to View in Properties Panel.
Then i repositioning the Camera View to the center, while press Shift + Alt keyboard.
And i do mouse scroll to make it bigger.
Appreciate to other comments too.